# Conversion of swagger json specification to the static html file in .NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net, swagger

I'm trying to find the .NET/C# solution for the conversion of swagger json specification to the static html file. I've found the alternatives for Java and Node.js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootprint-swagger (works completely as we need, but we can use node.js in our environment),
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#generating-static-html-api-documentation, but nothing for .NET

Probably you guys met or did something similar in .NET?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you've the swagger spec (yaml/json), you can generate the static HTML documentation or API clients using the online code generator (https://generator.swagger.io) without using .NET/C#. Here is an example:

```
curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" -d '{"swaggerUrl":"http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json"}' https://generator.swagger.io/api/gen/clients/html
```

and here is a sample response:

```
{"code":"1445940806041","link":"https://generator.swagger.io/api/gen/download/1445940806041"}
```

You can then download the zipped HTML documentation from the link.

***Note***: If you don't have a swaggerUrl, you can use a valid swagger JSON object (must be valid json!!) as well. Just empty the swaggerUrl property and add your schema to the spec property.

Comment: thanks for the option, but unfortunately we are unable to post our swagger specifications to out-of-company resources.. So I'm looking for the offline html generator.. Anyway thank you for your answer!

Comment: you can host the generator internally: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen but your server needs to have Java installed.

Comment: yep, got it.. but our servers do not have Java or Node.. and we are not allowed to install them. thanks.