# How to generate a Swagger #definition from sample JSON

Tags: json, swagger

Take the following #definition from the pet store example. Given a #definition section a JSON structure can be generated

e.g.
[image: Coversion of definition to JSON]

Is there something that can do the reverse given a largeish complex JSON file?

Given the below JSON Structure can I get the #defintion section of a swagger file generated to save some typing

```
{
  "variable": "sample",
  "object1": {
    "obj-field1": "field 1 of object",
    "obj-field2": "field 2 of object",
    "anArray": [
      "Value 1",
      {
        "anArrayObj1": "obj1fieldinarray",
        "anArrayObj2": "obj2fieldinarray"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conversion of swagger json specification to the static html file in .NET/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33395223/conversion-of-swagger-json-specification-to-the-static-html-file-in-net-c)

Answer (score 91):

You can use this JSON-to-OpenAPI schema converter:
https://roger13.github.io/SwagDefGen/

([GitHub project](https://github.com/Roger13/SwagDefGen))

I haven't used it personally though, so I'm not sure how good it is.

Since OpenAPI uses a subset of JSON Schema, you could also use one of the [JSON Schema generators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7341537/113116), however you may need to manually tweak the generated definition to make it OpenAPI-compatible.

Answer (score 26):

1 - Paste a response in http://www.mocky.io and get a link to your response

2 - Go to https://inspector.swagger.io/ and make a call to your example response

3 - Select the call from "History" and click "Create API definition"

4 - The swagger definition will be available at https://app.swaggerhub.com/

Comment: This creates a basic Swagger/OpenAPI doc, but it doesn't include the `definitions` section that the OP specifically wants

Comment: Yes, this doesn't include the response structure

Answer (score 7):

You can use [mock-to-openapi](https://github.com/OzzyCzech/mock-to-openapi) cli tool that generates [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/specification/) `YAML` files from `JSON` mock.

```bash
npm install --global mock-to-openapi
```

then run the conversion of all `*.json` files from the folder:

```bash
mock-to-openapi ./folder/*.json`
```

Let's have, for example, `json` object with:

```json
{
    "title": "This is title",
    "author": "Roman Ožana",
    "content" : "This is just an example",
    "date": "2020-05-12T23:50:21.817Z"
}
```

Tool `mock-to-openapi` converts `JSON` to the OpenAPI specification as follows:

```yaml
type: object
properties:
  title:
    type: string
    example: This is title
  author:
    type: string
    example: Roman Ožana
  content:
    type: string
    example: This is just an example
  date:
    type: string
    format: date-time
    example: 2020-05-12T23:50:21.817Z
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

**Generate Swagger REST-client code (and POJO) from sample JSON**:

1. Go to **apistudio.io**:

   - Insert -> New Model.
   - CutNpaste your JSON.
   - [The Swagger YML file will be generated]
   - Download -> YAML.
2. Go to **editor.swagger.io**:

   - CutNpaste the YML saved from last step.
   - Generate Client -> jaxrs-cxf-client (there are many other options).

Comment: apistudio.io is no longer available