# Generating YAML file (OPEN API) from a response body of my API?

Tags: api, rest, swagger, openapi-generator

I have made different APIs in Rest mode, and I want to generate the OPEN API file **automatically**, from the body of a response (JSON format) uploaded by my API.

**Does such a tool exist?**

I try with the POSTMAN, but the body documentation is very poor, just an illustration of an example

I try with SWAGGER.EDITOR, but we need to describe everything manually, and I have a response body with more than 300 fields

Answer (score 0):

You will find this question useful:

[How to generate a Swagger #definition from sample JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277137/how-to-generate-a-swagger-definition-from-sample-json#49277426)

It describes multiple options to solve your needs.